# imap headers of a quoted mail

Tags: php, zend-framework, email, imap, email-headers

I'm sending an email with some xheader.

When the recipient of the email replays to that email, i want to parse it, and get the content of that xheader from the mail i get by replay.

unfortunately, when i'm parsing the email i get back, i don't see my xheader.
(I printed the whole email, and the xheader is not there)

How can i do that in PHP with Zend Framework (i'm using Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap)?

Code:

```
    $mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap(array(
    'host' => 'pop.gmail.com',
    'user' => 'a@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'a',
    'ssl' => 'SSL'
));
$count = $mail->countMessages();
$message = $mail->getMessage($count);   
print_r($message);

    //go through the message
    foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($message) as $part){
        echo '*****************<br/>';
        print_r($part);
        echo '<br/>*****************<br/>';         
        //match parts content type to text/html - the one that maches is the message HTML body
        if (preg_match('/.*text\/html.*/', $part->contentType)){
            $body = $part->getContent();
        }

        $headers = $part->getHeaders();
        if (isset($headers['X-aHeader'])){
            echo $headers['X-aHeader'];
        }
```

Thanks,
Boris.

Comment: Where are you sending the mail from? Are you sure the header doesn't get removed by one of the mail servers involved?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure. i tried to send the mail directly to the box from which im parsing the mail, and when iv'e printed the mail - the header was there.

Comment: Well..i't might be removed by the email server used when replaying. guess i have nothing to do in that case, right?

Comment: If it's present in the target box, then it should be there. It will however definitely be lost when replying. I don't think mail clients  include the headers when replying.

Answer (score 0):

Pekka gets points for the correct response here - X-headers in an original message will not necessarily be retained for any replies to that message. But, you're using Gmail, so you have another potential option.

Gmail allows plus addressing, so username@gmail.com will also receive mail for username+extra@gmail.com. If your `X-aHeader` content is alphanumeric, you can append it to your email address (e.g. a+headerdata@gmail.com). If your header content *isn't* alphanumeric, I'd recommend caching what you *would* put in the header locally on your system, and provide a `uniqid` as the email plus-address. When you receive a reply, you can use that `uniqid` to look up the data you cached locally.

This is a common technique for uniquely identifying recipients who reply to emails, or who perhaps bounce messages.